# Ubuntu can't see any of my files

Tags: files

I just installed Ubuntu and I am enjoying its refreshing look. However when I click pictures or videos nothing loads at all. Even my Downloads folder shows as empty.

Where are all my files from my Windows account? It's just me on the computer and no other user. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Also where are all my files I created in Windows like my My Documents folder and subfolders in my My Documents folder.

Comment: Did you install alongside Windows, or did you select "use entire drive"?

Comment: Earlier Ubuntu had an option to scan your profile for documents but these days it was removed. So even if you did not erase Windows you have to make links to your folders manually. The command `ln -sd <target> <description>` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Ubuntu along with Windows, when you open up Ubuntu, in your file manager there should be a side bar that lists all your primary folders, Music, Documents, Desktop, Etc. At the top there should be a section that says "Devices" under that there should be a device that says "64 GB Filesystem" (fill in 64 GB with whatever size your partition is) if you click on that it should show your Windows files. You might need a password, but I doubt it.  Hope I answered your question correctly! :)

Comment: The Windows file systems and the Linux file systems are separate, from what I've experienced.  You can save files to either partition though.

Comment: but how do i access them? I have no link of the left side that says devices at all :(. I really like the look of this but i cant even get to my programs! If i cant even use whats installed or access my files, im not sure i see a point.

Comment: In my file manager the Windows partition shows up under "OS" in the side bar under devices.  Is there any way you can post a screenshot of your file manager?